# C++ create an array with type of template base class without specifying the template argument

Tags: c++, arrays, types, abstract

For example I have some base type Any

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Any
{
public:
    T data;
    Any(T data) { this->data = data; }
    // some other function signatures using data
};

class Number : public Any<int>
{
    // functions defining all functions like substracting etc.
};
```

And more classes deriving Any

Now in main function I want to create an array of Any

```cpp
int main()
{
    Any types[2] { Number(1), Number(3) }; // doesnt work
}
```

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: `Any` is a template not a type.

Comment: You should declare the type of **Any** like **Any<int> types[2]{anynumbre,any number}** , and do  not miss this "**;**"

Comment: What if I have more classes derived from Any, like String, Float, etc.

Comment: @DavitBaghdasaryan You'll need to provide the template argument as you can't use `Any` as a type-specifier because it is not a type in the first place. This means you can use `Any<int>` or `Any<double>` etc. See this dupe also ["error: Expected a type, got 'classname'" in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705707/error-expected-a-type-got-classname-in-c)

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without templates such that I can declare the array as Any but put derived classes in it and access data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have:

```
class A : public Any<int> { };

class B : public Any<std::string> { };

class C : public Any<double> { };
```

Objects of type `A`, `B`, and `C` are not subclasses of `Any` because `Any` is a template. Rather they are subclasses of `Any<int>`, `Any<std::string>` and `Any<double>`, respectively and as such do not share a common parent class.

You may wish to read up on [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).